# Poor Dvorak (a limerick)

Tags: cipher, limerick

> A famous composer named Dvorak
>   Decided to open his door rack.
>   But then Dvorak slipped,
>   And suddenly tripped,
>   Abe u.nn d.aeucpoy cbyr yd. unrrp pajtv

The last line of the limerick is all jumbled. What happened to poor Dvorak?

Comment: Way too obvious.

Comment: I guess it's a sort of "you know it or you don't" sort of riddle. I can guarantee you that anyone who hasn't heard of the Dvorak layout wouldn't have gotten it so quickly.

Comment: That's true, but the chances are rather high on Stack Exchange, after all.

Comment: Reminds me of [Perplex City Card 1/239](http://perplexcitycardcatalog.com/1/239/)

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't mind easy riddles if they're still fun and clever.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last line is:

> And fell headfirst into the floor rack.

The line was encrypted by typing in the [Dvorak keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) as if the keys were still in the standard QWERTY layout.

You can use [this keyboard](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/KB_United_States_Dvorak.svg/2000px-KB_United_States_Dvorak.svg.png) for reference.

Comment: Pretty much. Too fast :(

Comment: Could you please explain better your answer? It's too brief, I didn't understand what's the link between dvorak and qwerty.

Comment: I got your back, @leoll2. ;)

Comment: I can't find the the letter F in the jumbled.. And there is only one O in the jumbled but there are three in the answer.. Kindly explain.. thanks

Comment: I don't mean "jumbled" as in "rearranged", just in the sense of "nonsensical".

Comment: Ah, now I understand! Cool puzzle! Thanks @JoeZ.

Comment: Jumbled is often a key word for an anagram so that could make things confusing, but then again you don't want it to be too easy now would you? though apperently Ray knew about dvorak as being a keyboard layout, I would have never made that link xD